# Bootstrap typeahed is one character behind using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, elasticsearch

I am using `bootstrap typeahead` ([GitHub](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)) to create search forms. After user inputs something I am doing `elasticsearch query` using `elasticsearch.js` and returning results. The problem is that results displayed in typeahead are always one character behind, not suggesting correct values.

**Typeahead input:**

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" class="form-control typeahead" id="searchInputId" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off">
```

**Here is my code:**

```
var elasticsearchAddress = "exampleserver.com:9200";
var elasticsearchClient = createElasticsearchClient(elasticsearchAddress);

var data = [];
$("#searchInputId").typeahead({ source:data, items:10, fitToElement:true });
$("#searchInputId").on("input", function(){
    var searchTerm = $("#searchInputId").val();
    elasticsearchMathPhrasePrefixSearch(elasticsearchClient, searchTerm, function () {
        $("#searchInputId").data('typeahead').source = getElasticsearchSearchResultsArray();
    });
});
```

**`elasticsearchMathPhrasePrefixSearch() function`**

```
function elasticsearchMathPhrasePrefixSearch(client, searchPhrase, callback) {
    console.log("Searching for: " + searchPhrase);
    client.search({
        body: {
            "query": {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                    "accountName": searchPhrase
                }
            }
        }
    }, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.trace('ELASTICSEARCH: Search query failed');
        } else {
            console.log('ELASTICSEARCH: Search query OK');
            var doc = response.hits.hits;
            elasticsearchSearchResultsArray = getDocs(doc);
        }
        callback();
    });
}
```

**`getDocs() function`**

```
function getDocs(doc){
    var searchResultsArray=[];
    for(var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++){
        searchResultsArray.push(doc[i]._source.accountName);
    }
    return searchResultsArray;
```

**`getElasticsearchSearchResultsArray() function`**

```
function getElasticsearchSearchResultsArray(){
    return elasticsearchSearchResultsArray;
}
```

`elasticsearchSearchResultsArray` is a global array that holds the results. Because of the JS async nature I had no other idea to make it work.

**EDIT:**

Ok, I modified my code so the source is updated correctly with help of this [Issue #1997](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1997). But now I have got another problem. The typeahead dropdown is not displayed when I type.

**My new code:**

```
var empty = [];
$("#searchInputId").typeahead({ source:empty, items:10, fitToElement:true });
$("#searchInputId").on("keyup", function(ev){

            ev.stopPropagation();
            ev.preventDefault();

            //filter out up/down, tab, enter, and escape keys
            if( $.inArray(ev.keyCode,[40,38,9,13,27]) === -1 ){
                var self = $(this);

                //set typeahead source to empty
                self.data('typeahead').source = [];

                //active used so we aren't triggering duplicate keyup events
                if( !self.data('active') && self.val().length > 0){
                    self.data('active', true);

                    //Do data request. Insert your own API logic here.
                    var searchTerm = self.val();
                    elasticsearchMathPhrasePrefixSearch(elasticsearchClient, searchTerm, function() {

                        //set this to true when your callback executes
                        self.data('active',true);

                        //set your results into the typehead's source
                        self.data('typeahead').source = getElasticsearchSearchResultsArray();

                        //trigger keyup on the typeahead to make it search
                        self.trigger('keyup');

                        //All done, set to false to prepare for the next remote query.
                        self.data('active', false);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolved it myself. I switched from bootstrap3-typeahead to [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). It is working great and the script is much smaller.

New code:

```
$("#searchInputId").on("keydown", function () {
            $("#searchInputId").autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    var searchTerm = $("#searchInputId").val();
                    elasticsearchMathPhrasePrefixSearch(elasticsearchClient, searchTerm, function (){
                        response(getElasticsearchSearchResultsArray());
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `on("keyup")` instead. input is 1 character behind.

Comment: Seems to be working. But now the problem is that dropdown with suggestions is not displaying when I retrieve the results too late. Is there a way to display it always after results are retrieved?

Comment: This is because you are calling your callback(); method outside of the function (error, response) callback. call it on the bottom of this callback and you are sure the callback only gets called when te request was finished! If the answer is right please mark it :)

Comment: `function (error, response) {
        //...
            elasticsearchSearchResultsArray = getDocs(doc);
        }
        callback();
    });`

Comment: This does not seem to fix it.

Comment: @jpiechowka can you update your question to show your new code? then I can check if it is in the right location.

Comment: try to destroy the typeahead: $('#typeahead_input_element').typeahead('destroy') and then reinitialise it with: $("#searchInputId").typeahead({ source: getElasticsearchSearchResultsArray(), items: getElasticsearchSearchResultsArray.length, fitToElement:true }); simply setting the source doesn't update it.

Comment: After destroying the typeahead I got no `on(keyup)` events

Comment: Yes you probably need to re register that as well

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to reflect recent changes I did. I can update typeahead source in the right time now, but the typeahead dropdown is not displayed. Can I show it manually somehow?